# Error with no return type

Tags: java

hi i am getting an error in my method saying that my method has no return type which is confusing because it has a return type;

```
public double getPhoneRates() {

    final int freeminutes=50;
    double totalcharge;
    double chargeperminute = 0.10;
    double d = 0;

    if(b.regularService() == true){
        if(b.getMinutes()<=50)
            return totalcharge=0;
        else 
            d=b.getMinutes()-freeminutes;

        d = d * chargeperminute;
        return totalcharge= freeminutes +d;
    }
}
```

Comment: logic101 - you might try to format your code example so it's easier to read.  It would help someone trying to answer your question.

Comment: yes, but it is nested inside your if-statement

Comment: Is this the whole method?  It's missing at least a closing-bracket

Comment: What if `b.regularService() == false`? Then your function does not return anything (a.k.a. no double is returned!).

Comment: all code paths need a return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work for you:

```
public double getPhoneRates()
{
  final int freeminutes = 50;
  double chargeperminute = 0.10;
  double d = 0;
  if (b.regularService() == true)
  {
    if (b.getMinutes() <= 50) return 0;
    else d = b.getMinutes() - freeminutes;
    d *= chargeperminute;
    d += freeminutes;
  }
  return d;
}
```

In all the cases there should be a return in your method.

And it is usually a better code that returns at only one place from a method.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
public double getPhoneRates()
{
  final int freeminutes = 50;
  double chargeperminute = 0.10;
  double d = 0;
  if (b.regularService() == true)
  {
    if (b.getMinutes() <= 50) return 0; //return 0
    else d = b.getMinutes() - freeminutes; 
    d = d * chargeperminute; 
    return freeminutes + d; //return result
  }

  return -1; //some default value
}
```

Comment: @Peter, i just picked an arbitrary #, idk what the OP wants as a default

Comment: If phone company ever starts charging at a rate of -1, I will join tomorrow. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check your braces.  You don't always hit a return statement in your method.

Answer (score 0):

If you plainly copied the code then a closing brace `}` seems to be missing.. in addition not all the branches of the flow seems to return something.